How to get rid of 0 values from extract, as I think it's causing first and last row to aggregate and give false rows in Oracle?
What I am wanting to do, for each employee, is to get the difference between their clockin, and their next respective clockin in hours, and I am utilizing lag.  The problem is, the below select gives me the resulting extract(single employee), and I think the 0/zero row is causing the issue, and also causing a false row(s) when I pull multiple employees(second extract screenshot).
Here is my select:
SELECT DISTINCT
 p.emp_name,
 e.emp_id,
 TO_CHAR(ce.clockin_dt_tm), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' clockin,
 (NVL(ce.clockin_dt_tm - LAG(ce.clockin_dt_tm) OVER(PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY e.emp_id),0)*24) between_clockins

Resulting extract for single employee:

Resulting extract for multiple employees(red is employee one-same as single employee above, blue is employee 2):

I think if I can get rid of the 0/zero values, that will fix what I need.

How would I go about getting rid and/or have SQL not consider the 0/zero values for calculation?
If #1 is not the issue, is there anything I can adjust to make it come out correctly?

Any and all help/directions/references/guidance greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Roland


If you want to ignore the first row during aggregation then do not wrap the expressions calculating the difference in NVL and just leave it to be NULL.
If you want the difference between the current row and the previous row based on timestamps then ORDER BY ce.clockin_dt_tm and not ORDER BY e.emp_id.

Like this:
SELECT e.emp_name,
       e.emp_id,
       TO_CHAR(ce.clockin_dt_tm), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' clockin,
       (
         ce.clockin_dt_tm
         - LAG(ce.clockin_dt_tm) OVER(
             PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY ce.clockin_dt_tm
           )
       )*24 AS between_clockins
FROM   employees e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_clockins ce
       ON (ce.emp_id = e.emp_id)

If you then want to aggregate and find the average difference:
SELECT MAX(emp_name) AS emp_name,
       emp_id,
       AVG(between_clockins) AS average_between_clockins
FROM   (
  SELECT e.emp_name,
         e.emp_id,
         TO_CHAR(ce.clockin_dt_tm), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' clockin,
         (
           ce.clockin_dt_tm
           - LAG(ce.clockin_dt_tm) OVER(
               PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY ce.clockin_dt_tm
             )
         )*24 AS between_clockins
  FROM   employees e
         LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_clockins ce
         ON (ce.emp_id = e.emp_id)
)
GROUP BY emp_id

If you also want to filter out the times when the difference was zero then add a WHERE filter:
SELECT MAX(emp_name) AS emp_name,
       emp_id,
       AVG(between_clockins) AS average_between_clockins
FROM   (
  SELECT e.emp_name,
         e.emp_id,
         TO_CHAR(ce.clockin_dt_tm), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' clockin,
         (
           ce.clockin_dt_tm
           - LAG(ce.clockin_dt_tm) OVER(
               PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY ce.clockin_dt_tm
             )
         )*24 AS between_clockins
  FROM   employees e
         LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_clockins ce
         ON (ce.emp_id = e.emp_id)
)
WHERE  between_clockins > 0
GROUP BY emp_id

fiddle

@MTO That did it!!  Thank you so much.   I wound up using "ORDER BY ce.clockin_dt_tm " from your first code section above but going to keep everything for my resources.  Thanks again!
